# Use variables in filename with INTO OUTFILE (timestamped filename)

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT *
FROM project
INTO OUTFILE 'C:\desktop\[timestamped filename like 01/05/2014.csv]';
```

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: SET @OUTFILE = CONCAT( CONCAT('C:\\Users\\harinath.mn\\Desktop\\New folder\\reports1-', NOW()), '.csv');

select * from project into outfile '@OUTFILE' ;       I have used it but once it showed rows effected but again when is execute it shows error code 1086

Answer (score 1):

Has said in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11338404/rename-outfile-with-date-in-mysql/11338469#11338469), you can use:

```
SET @sql_text = 
   CONCAT (
       "SELECT * FROM `project ` into outfile 'C:\desktop\"
       , DATE_FORMAT( NOW(), '%d/%m/%Y')
       , ".csv'"
    );

PREPARE s1 FROM @sql_text;
EXECUTE s1;
DROP PREPARE s1;
```

Thanks [Haim Evgi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/74314/haim-evgi) for the original answer.

Max.